# What’s the meaning of the lyrics “Teenagers now I know I wild eat their young”?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, lyrics

This lyrics comes from Tough Love by PattyCake Productions. Could you please help me analyze the structure of this lyrics? And is the word “wild” used as an adverb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several sources online that claim these are the lyrics:

> — https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/PattyCake/Tough-Love-The-Villains-Lair
>
> — https://www.shazam.com/track/466432924/tough-love-the-villains-lair

The transcription is incorrect. This is not grammatical.

I listened to the song myself. The lyrics move very fast — this line is almost in double-time — so it’s understandable that it was transcribed incorrectly.  My interpretation is:

> - **Teenagers!!**
> - ***Now*** I know why the wild eat their young.

If you have had — or know — teenagers — I’m sure you know why the **exclamation** or **interjection** “Teenagers!” makes sense on its own.

“The wild eat their young” means “Wild animals sometimes eat their own offspring.”

**Your interpretation may vary.**